# Grails 3 and Spring Security Plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security, gradle, grails-plugin, grails-3.0

I've just recently started working with Grails, and I'd like to test out the Spring Security Plugin.  I'm using Grails v3.0.0RC2, and I'm finding it difficult to come across accurate documentation for it with a lot of things.

I'm looking at the Grails page for the Spring Security Plugin, located at http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core, and it tells me to add the following to grails-app/conf/BuildConfig

```
plugins {
  …
  compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC4'
  …
}
```

Now, Grails 3 has done away with the BuildConfig, and moved over to using Gradle. So I figured I could just that compile line to my "dependencies" section in build.gradle and it would work, like so:

```
dependencies{
  ...
  compile:":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
}
```

However, that did not work. I get the error "Could not find :spring-security-core:2.0-RC4...".

Then I figured, 'Hey, it's a plugin, let me try prefacing it with "org.grails.plugins" like I see elsewhere in the build.gradle file:

```
dependencies{
  ...
  compile:"org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
}
```

And still no go.

I have gotten it to compile by adding the dependency found on search.maven.org, like so:

```
dependencies{
  ...
  compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:4.0.0.RELEASE'
}
```

But I don't think thats the proper way to do, because Grails documentation says I should have access to the command

```
grails s2-quickstart
```

once the plugin is installed, which I do not when I do it using the Maven repo.

I'm sure there's a simple configuration error I'm making, as I'm very new to both Grails, Spring, and Gradle, so I appreciate any help that can be provided.

Comment: The spring security plugin is not Grails 3 compatible.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Thanks for the quick reply. Where did you find this information? All I saw related to compatibility was on the Grails plugin page, and it said it was compatible with 2.3.0+. It would have been nice if I had come across that in the documentation somewhere prior to trying to get it to work.

Comment: see my answer for further details.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Spring Secuirty core plugin for Grails is not Grails 3 compatible. However, since Grails 3 is based on Spring Boot you can use the [Spring Security Starter for Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) instead.

This has been [discussed](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/grails-dev-discuss/spring$20security/grails-dev-discuss/jOF0jw_BiCs/tOxd0NZpaxkJ) on the Grails developers mailing list and going forward many Grails plugins will not be moved to Grails 3 and instead will be replaced by pure Spring solutions.

**Update**

Since this question was originally asked there has been a Spring Security plugin created for Grails 3.x. It can be found here: https://bintray.com/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/view

Comment: Not actually. There is a plugin for Grails 3. I am currently using it. This is an update since this question was asked a while ago. Here is the link https://bintray.com/grails/plugins/org.grails.plugins%3Aspring-security-core/view#files

Comment: Josh: there is a plugin for Spring 3 now available... but there's no documentation on it whatsoever. I was wondering if you had tried and what your assessment of it was.

Comment: The link seems broken

Answer (score 8):

The "Spring Security Starter for Spring Boot" is a good starting point, but if you want to save yourself some time trying to figure out how to get it to work with Grails, check out this [helpful blog post](http://spiesdavid.blogspot.com/2015/03/grails-3-app-with-security-part-1.html).

Answer (score 4):

I wrote [the blog post](http://spiesdavid.blogspot.com/2015/03/grails-3-app-with-security-part-1.html) @Jamie referenced in his answer and I added [a new blog post](http://spiesdavid.blogspot.com/2015/05/grails-3-app-with-security-part-2-gorm.html) describing how to use the Gorm domain classes from Spring-Security-Core plugin from Grails 2.

Answer (score 2):

```
dependencies {
     ...
     compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.4'
     ...
}
```

This is what I used and it worked for me