# Grails 3.0.2 cannot resolve @Secured annotation in controller

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, grails-3.0

I try upgrade my application from Grails 2.4.4 to Grails 3.0.2 and I have problem with spring annotation.

I have controller, like this:

```
import grails.plugins.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

class MyController {  

    @Secured(['ROLE_ADMINS_GROUP'])
    def index() {
        // some code
    }
}
```

In `depencencies` block in `build.gradle` I have this:

```
dependencies {
    provided 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging'
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"

    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"

    provided "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    provided "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    provided 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'

    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"

    console "org.grails:grails-console"

    compile "org.grails.plugins:wslite:0.7.2.0"
}
```

When i try compile my application, I get error message.

```
MyController.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class grails.plugins.springsecurity.annotation.Secured
@ line 4, column 1.
import grails.plugins.springsecurity.annotation.Secured
^
```

Comment: See this question please: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29286659/grails-3-and-spring-security-plugin). The error is happening because you're using imports from a plugin that you don't included in your dependencies and you can't do that since, as the answer above explain, the Spring Security Plugin isn't compatible with Grails 3.0. I don't know in the moment how to help you in this issue, but there are blog posts in that question that could help you, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security Core Plugin has already been updated and is now compatible with Grails 3.0 see the docs: [What's New in Version 3.0](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/newInV3.html)

Just add following dependency to the `dependencies` block of the `build.gradle` file:

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.0.M1"
```